# How to plot equation (x^2+y^2-1)^3=x^2*y^3?

Tags: r

As to equation like `(x^2+y^2-1)^3=x^2*y^3`,I use emdbook,

```
library(emdbook)
> curve3d((x^2+y^2-1)^3-x^2*y^3,
+         sys3d="contour",level=0,from=c(-10,-10),to=c(10,10),
+         drawlabels=FALSE,axes=FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
```

but get wrong plot [image],

How to plot `(x^2+y^2-1)^3=x^2*y^3` in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you subtract one side of the equation from the other, so the solutions are at 0, you can use `outer` to calculate a grid of `z` values, which `contour` can then plot:

```r
x <- seq(-2, 2, by = 0.01)    # high granularity for good resolution
z <- outer(x, x, FUN = function(x, y) x^2*y^3 - (x^2+y^2-1)^3)

# specify level to limit contour lines printed
contour(x, x, z, levels = 0)
```

[image]

or with the tidyverse,

```r
library(tidyverse)

crossing(x = seq(-2, 2, by = 0.01), 
         y = x) %>% 
    mutate(z = x^2*y^3 - (x^2+y^2-1)^3) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x, y, z = z)) + 
    geom_contour(breaks = 0)
```

[image]